# What should be the return type of this query?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am having a `lambda expression` which can fetch multiple records from my table.

Here is the expression

```
public sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Master GetDepositsPendingRecord(string glCode, int fromDateID)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
               var deposit = db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters.Where(deposits => deposits.cGLCode.Equals(glCode) && deposits.nFromDateID.Equals(fromDateID));
               return deposit; 
            }
        }
```

I am getting an Error `Cannot implicitly convert type IQueryable To Table Object`.

I want to return the table object to my `Update method` which will update some fileds of the result.

Here is my Update method

```
public void UpdatePendingRecords(string glCode, int fromDateID)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {

                var deposit = GetDepositsPendingRecord(glCode, fromDateID);

                foreach (var pending in deposit)
                {
                    pending.cAuthorizedStatus = "Authorized";
                    pending.dAuthorizedOn = DateTime.Now;
                    pending.cAuthorizedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

                }
}
}
```

Currently I am not able to get it working.

Can anyone help me with this query?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use First or FirstOrDefault extension method. For example, return deposit.First();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an `IQueryable<T>` where `T` is whatever type `sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters` is a table of. e.g. `IQueryable<Log_Deposits_Interest_Master>` etc.

Note that the table class that `sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters` is an instance of also implements that interface. The result is a different implementation that has information to know that it should take it's results from there, and also apply the filter in the `Where`.

You are also disposing of the context in the wrong place, because it won't exist by the time the values are enumerated through.

In this case, since you are going to work directly on the results rather than apply any further changes to the query, I'd `foreach` through the results and `yield` them in the method, so it gets turned into an enumeration block and the lifetime gets handled differently. Otherwise I'd either work to make sure the datacontext was alive longer by passing it into that method rather than creating it there, or at a pinch I wouldn't dispose it (but only at a pinch, while the linq2sql people have said not disposing datacontexts is safe, it goes against good practice - you should really assume that it's never safe to do that - also, it's only safe most times; do you want to learn when it is or isn't? Neither do I. Edit: Today by coincidence brings an example where it wasn't safe with https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002914/400547).

Edit with examples:

Best approach:

```
public IQueryable<Log_Deposits_Interest_Master> GetDepositsPendingRecord(DataClasses1DataContext db, string glCode, int fromDateID)
{
  return db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters.Where(deposits => deposits.cGLCode.Equals(glCode) && deposits.nFromDateID.Equals(fromDateID));
}

public void UpdatePendingRecords(string glCode, int fromDateID)
{
  using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
  {

    var deposit = GetDepositsPendingRecord(db, glCode, fromDateID);

    foreach (var pending in deposit)
    {
      pending.cAuthorizedStatus = "Authorized";
      pending.dAuthorizedOn = DateTime.Now;
      pending.cAuthorizedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

    }

    //presumably you want to call db.SubmitChanges() here, no?
  }
}
```

If you *really* had to include datacontext creation within the method called you could do

```
public IEnumerable<Log_Deposits_Interest_Master> GetDepositsPendingRecord(string glCode, int fromDateID)
{
  using(var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    foreach(Log_Deposits_Interest_Master item in db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters.Where(deposits => deposits.cGLCode.Equals(glCode) && deposits.nFromDateID.Equals(fromDateID))
      yield return item;
}
```

However this isn't very useful if you want save the changes you make back to the database, as to do that you must call `SubmitChanges()` on the same context that you got them from or else rebind them. It also means that if you were to add another `Where()` on, or use `Count()` or anything else that can be passed to the database, it won't be, as we've broken the queryable ability at that point.

Comment: Could you help me with a example.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Deleted my answer as this covers everything I wanted to say, but better :)

Comment: @Jon Hanna Thanks for the detailed answer.Really well explained.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters represents a collection of sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Master objects. Your Where query also returns a collection of objects (IQueriable) which can't be converted to a single object. If you are sure that your Where query returns one and only one entry, you can replace it with Single or SingleOrDefault statement with the same conditions inside. If it can return several object, but you need only the first one, you can use First or FirstOrDefault, also with the same conditions.

Comment: @EIDog My table will return multiple records.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the .ToList() extension then like this:

```
var deposit = db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters.Where(deposits => deposits.cGLCode.Equals(glCode) && deposits.nFromDateID.Equals(fromDateID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Why load every result into memory if they're only going to use one at a time?

Comment: calling the foreach loop will load it all into memory in anyway, it's just doing it two executions earlier.

Comment: Calling the foreach loop will load one into memory at a time, yours will load every one in first before passing it on as a unit - with a large result set that could be gigs of wasted memory and minutes of wasted time. Even with a small result set, using `ToList()` when you don't have a specific reason to (needing to know the size before the next operation, doing several passes on the same data) is premature pessimisation. Besides, if they're going to want to save the changes back to the database they'll need to hold onto the context anyway.