# Linq-to-SQL database file empty

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm new to stackoverflow an I've searched the whole site and the msdn and found nothing. I hope you can help me!

I want to have a Linq-to-SQL database in an `.sdf` file. So I designed the database sheme in the ORM designer for Linq-to-SQL and wrote the following code:

```
DataShemeDataContext context = new DataShemeDataContext("Data Source=database.sdf");
if (!context.DatabaseExists())
  context.CreateDatabase();
Console.ReadLine();
```

My problem is the following:

- when I run the program and exit it by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, everything is fine
- But if I click on the "X" button in the top of the console window, the database file is only 20kb size (instead of 84kb) and it is empty.

Using this line:

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

makes no difference.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Try waiting a while before you close the console with the "x" - I'm wondering if the CreateDatabase call might be asynchronous, but I wouldn't expect it to be... Not that familiar with Linq2SQL...

Comment: I've tried waiting but it won't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your code with an using :

```
using(DataShemeDataContext context = new DataShemeDataContext("Data Source=database.sdf"))
{
    if (!context.DatabaseExists())
        context.CreateDatabase();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This way you are sure that your context is properly disposed.

Comment: This works fine! So I have to do that in every method wich uses the context in order to prevent corrupt data?

Comment: As the DataContext implements IDisposable, it should be disposed when not needed anymore.

Comment: Applies to everything that implements `IDisposable`. While it's possible that in a given case it's safe to not `Dispose()` it, it's never wrong to do, and you normally won't know when those safe cases are, so just assume that you have to do it. The format mathieu gives will happen even in the face of error. Incidentally, the only reason your app worked from key-press the first time is graceful shutdown runs finalisers that will do clean-up that hasn't been done, but just killing the process (which happens to console apps when you close the console) won't.